# How to style custom views without using style attribute?

Tags: android

I passed the style reference through all the given constructors:

```
public MyCustomView(Context context)
{ 
    super(context, null, R.style.MyStyle);
}
public MyCustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{ 
    super(context, attrs, R.style.MyStyle);
}
public MyCustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
{ 
    super(context, attrs, R.style.MyStyle);
}
```

I'm trying this on MarshMallow. Style is not applied but works when applied through style attribute.

Comment: As far as I know there are 4 not 3 constructors of View

Comment: aren't there suppose to be `super` instead of `this`

Answer (score 0):

Try using three argument constructor with *ContextThemeWrapper* as follows:

```
MyCustomView mView = new MyCustomView(new ContextThemeWrapper(this,R.style.yourStyle),null,0);
```

While your MyCustomView class's constructor will be as follows:

```
    public MyCustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
{ 
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}
```

This should work.

Comment: But how to do it through xml?

Comment: You can override your _Activity_ or _Application's_ _theme_ properties by assigning custom styles to them and apply to the entire _Activity_ or _Application_ but if you want to style a single view inside your xml this is the only way I suppose you can do it through xml (by setting style attribute). And it makes sense also, nobody would need a way to do something like this some other way. [you should study this in detail here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html)